# CORS Option request blocked by custom JWE Filter in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, cors, spring-filter

## Problem

CORS OPTIONS request from the browser is entering my JWT Validation filter and returning a 401 on every request. I would expect the CORS OPTIONS request to be handled before entering the JWT Validation filter.

## Background

In my spring boot application I have created a JWT filter (which implements Filter) that intercepts every request. The filters only job is to validate the token and produce a 401 if the token is expired, has a bad signature, or the claims are incorrect and forward the request to the next filter in the chain if the token is valid.

```java
@Component
@Order(1)
public class JweFilter implements Filter {

  @Override
  doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain)
    throws IOException, ServletException {

    // Validate Token and return 401 if invalid

    chain.doFilter(request, response);

  }

}
```

I have enabled CORS by extending WebMvcConfigurer--which seems to be the modern approach.

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
class CorsConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

  @Override
  public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {

    registry.addMapping("/**")
      .allowedHeaders("*")
      .allowedMethods("*");
  }
}
```

Does anyone know why I am experiencing this behavior and how to fix it?

Thank you in advance for anyone that has information :)

Answer (score 0):

To fix the issue I got rid of the WebMvcConfigurer and replaced it with a FilterRegistrationBean https://spring.io/blog/2015/06/08/cors-support-in-spring-framework#filter-based-cors-support

```java
@Configuration
public class MyConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public FilterRegistrationBean corsFilter() {
        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        CorsConfiguration config = new CorsConfiguration();
        config.setAllowCredentials(true);
        config.addAllowedOrigin("http://domain1.com");
        config.addAllowedHeader("*");
        config.addAllowedMethod("*");
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", config);
        FilterRegistrationBean bean = new FilterRegistrationBean(new CorsFilter(source));
        bean.setOrder(0);
        return bean;
    }
}
```

With this code in place the CORS preflight request was handled by the FilterRegistrationBean before hitting the JWT Validation Filter.